# Add Static Values To JSON Objects In AWS CDK Step Function Stack

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I have this object that requires a key/value pair to be added to it of `status: 0` in the product object. How do I do that natively?

**Current JSON:**

```
{
    "referring_website": "https://example.com",
    "magento_request": {
        "product": {
          "price": 125,
        }
     }
}
```

**Desired JSON Result:**

```
{
    "referring_website": "https://example.com",
    "magento_request": {
        "product": {
          "price": 125,
          "status": 0
        }
     }
}
```

**AWS CDK Code Example:**
*To highlight the requirements*

```
this.createProduct = new SqsSendMessage(this, "Create Product ", {
  messageBody: TaskInput.fromObject({
    "data": {
       ...JsonPath.stringAt("$.magento_request.product"),
       "status": 0
     }
  }),
  ...
});
```

What can I do in the `data` key to add `status: 0` to the product object?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this?

```
this.createProduct = new SqsSendMessage(this, "Create Product ", {
    messageBody: TaskInput.fromObject({
        "product": {
            "price": JsonPath.stringAt("$.magento_request.product.price"),
            "status": 0
        }
    }),
    ...
});
```

Comment: This example works (without needing to check it), however, I just need the product object, as it varies what is it in.